# Windows 10\11 - wont shutdown\sleep\restart\run-as-admin

Tags: windows, shutdown, reboot, runas

After hours of searching, I've got a very weird problem that I couldn't find a solution to.

Since I upgraded my rig to Intel's 12gen (new motherboard, CPU, RAM, installation), I sometimes have the following problem:

- PC won't shut down, go to sleep, or restart.
- When I click shutdown in the start menu - nothing happens
- when I run the `shutdown` command - nothing happens
- When I click the power button - nothing happens
- When this bug occurs, I also won't be able to start programs as admin - right-clicking on programs - run as admin - noting happens

After a random amount of minutes, suddenly, all the previous commands will execute, sometimes 3-4 minutes after clicking.

I don't have any anti-virus installed except Windows Defender.

This happened in a clean installation of Windows 10 and now a clean installation of Windows 11.

When checking Event Viewer, I can see an event at the very second I clicked "shut down" (even when it seems that nothing has happened):

```
The process C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe has initiated the power off of the computer on behalf of user **** for the following reason: Other (Unplanned)
```

Any thoughts? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I believe it to be relevant. I had a problem with a mechanical HDD once, mouse clicks would be delayed for a short amount of time, then suddenly just as you describe everything would catch up.  This behavior went on for months, DISM and SFC scans showed zero problems with the system files, this behavior went out until one day suddenly the system BSOD and wouldn't boot. The only thing that was different is I could shutdown my system, of course, I never tried to do that when the mouse commands were delayed. So you can see the reason I saw similarities in the behavior you described.

Comment: While you had Windows 11 installed it could have been the NVMe IOPS issue, but that was resolved with KB5007262, which was released last month.  The security update that includes the fix will be released this month.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an error in Windows 10. First, boot up elevated `cmd` and run

```
C:\%WinDir%\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management Tool
Version: 10.X.XXXXX.XXX

Image Version: 10.X.XXXXX.XXX

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\%WinDir%\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan. This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

C:\%WinDir%\system32>
```

Restart your computer. Check if the problem persists.

If `sfc` says that it `found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.`  you will have to repair the corrupted files manually. For more details head to

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e
```

Comment: Problem is I can't reproduce the problem, it just happen once every few days... I will use procmon next time it happens

Comment: Just do it - `dism` and `sfc` will check whether your system has any corrupted files and repair them.

Comment: It didnt find any problems. It also didnt make much sense that there were corrupted files, same files, in two separate Windows installations. I highly suspect a faulty driver to cause this.